# Displaying list of employees in listview

Tags: android, listview

### Displaying list of employees in listview using arrayList

- **list of employees** :: sam, max, carl
- what code must be added (changes to be made) for `MainActivity.java` to
  achive the functionalityusing bean class `employee.java`

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

**Employee.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Employee implements Serializable{
    private String Name;
    public void SetName(String name){
        this.Name=name;
    }
    public String GetName(){
        return Name;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView-ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Employee> AL=new ArrayList<Employee>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView TV1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);



    }

}
```

**Thanks**,

Comment: use a custom listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what code must be added (changes to be made) for MainActivity.java to
>   achive the functionalityusing bean class employee.java

It' not too tricky. If you don't want some special / custom ListView (custom items in list) you just need:

- properly initialise ListView
- create ListAdapter (in your case would be enough system build-in
  ArrayAdapter
- to be able to show name of employees you need to override `toString()`
  method in your Employee class (otherwise will be printed string
  representation ob object that is not very human readable)

### Example:

Updated class:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
       return this.name;
    }
}
```

Example of initialisation and assigning of ArrayAdapter:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findVieById(R.id.listid);
ArrayAdapter<Employee> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Employee>(<context>, 
                                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, <list>);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

### Note:

If you want customize list items you need to create own XML layout for list-row a implement own ListAdapter (extending for example from BaseAdapter). If you don't know how to start look at:

- [Android ListView - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/)

Answer (score 2):

```
**You need to set Custom Adapter to your Listview. And in getView() method inflate your custom layout, as in below example.******** 


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Employee> emp_arrayList=new ArrayList<Employee>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      // Add Data to your ArrayList<Employee>

        Employee e=new Employee();
        e.setName("AAA");
        e.setSalary("23000");
        e.setName("Infi");
        emp_arrayList.add(e);
        Employee e1=new Employee();
        e1.setName("BBB");
        e1.setSalary("27000");
        e1.setName("Wipro");
        emp_arrayList.add(e1);

        **ListView l=findViewById(R.id.listView-id);
        MyAdapter adapter=new Adapter();
        l.setAdapter(l);
        l.notifyDataSetChanged();**


    }

}




class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return emp_arrayList.size();
        }
   @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return emp_arrayList.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup  rootLayout) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             View v = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(rootLayout.getContext(), R.layout.yourcustomlayout,null); 


          TextView employeename=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.empname);
          TextView employeesalary=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.empsalary);
          TextView employeecompany=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.empcompany);

                  employeename.setText(emp_arrayList.get(position).getName());
                  employeesalary.setText(emp_arrayList.get(position).getSalary());
                  employeecompany.setText(emp_arrayList.get(position).getCompany());
        return v;
    }``
}



I hope this will help you.
```